# convert data that is in the form of object in a csv to a pivot

Tags: pandas, csv, seaborn, data-analysis

I have a file that is not beautiful and searchable so i downloaded it in the csv format. It contains 4 columns and 116424 rows.
I'm not able to plot its three columns namely Year, Age and Ratio onto a heat map.
The link for the csv file is:  https://gist.github.com/JustGlowing/1f3d7ff0bba7f79651b00f754dc85bf1

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy.random import randn
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('new_file.csv')
print(df.info())
print(df.shape)
couple_columns = df[['Year','Age','Ratio']]
print(couple_columns.head())
```

Error

C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/Pranav/PycharmProjects/takenmind/Data_Visualization/a1.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
RangeIndex: 116424 entries, 0 to 116423
  File "C:/Users/Pranav/PycharmProjects/takenmind/Data_Visualization/a1.py", line 12, in 
Data columns (total 4 columns):
    couple_columns = df[['Year','Age','Ratio']]
AREA     116424 non-null object
  File "C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2682, in **getitem**
YEAR     116424 non-null int64
AGE      116424 non-null object
RATIO    116424 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 2.2+ MB
None
(116424, 4)
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2726, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: "['Year' 'Age' 'Ratio'] not in index"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your columns are uppercase from the info output: `YEAR 116424 non-null int64`. You should be able to get e.g. the year column with `df[['YEAR']]`.

If you would rather use lowercase, you can use
`df = pd.read_csv('new_file.csv').rename(columns=str.lower)`

Comment: I want to create a pivot table data frame with Year along x-axes, Age Range along y-axes and Sex-Ratio filled within cells.
 and then plot a heatmap using seaborn for the pivot table that was just created.

Answer (score 0):

The csv has some text in the top 8 lines before your actual data begins. You can skip those by using the `skiprows` argument

`df = pd.read_csv('f2m_ratios.csv', skiprows=8)`

Lets say you want to plot heatmap only for one Area

```
df = df[df['Area'] == 'Afghanistan']
```

Before you plot a heatmap, you need data in a certain format (pivot table)

```
df = df.pivot('Year','Age','Ratio')
```

Now your dataframe is ready for a heatmap

```
sns.heatmap(df)
```